# How I split particular column data from the dataset in R

Tags: r

I have below client dataset includes client_id, birth_number and district_id. The birth number is in the form `YYMMDD`, here is twist  - The value is in the form: `YYMMDD`(for Men) and the value is in the form: `YY(+50MM)DD`(for Women). I want your help to develop the script in R where we can split the `YYMMDD` and set condition. based on condition if `MM>12` then that row belong to women and the actual month value subtracted by 15 else Men with the same birth number.
please help

The value is in the form: `YYMMDD` (for men)
The value is in the form: `YY(+50MM)DD` (for women)

```
"client_id";"birth_number";"district_id"
1;"706213";18
2;"450204";1
3;"406009";1
4;"561201";5
5;"605703";5
6;"190922";12
7;"290125";15
8;"385221";51
9;"351016";60
10;"430501";57
11;"505822";57
12;"810220";40
13;"745529";54
14;"425622";76
15;"185828";21
16;"190225";21
17;"341013";76
18;"315405";76
19;"421228";47
20;"790104";46
21;"526029";12
22;"696011";1
23;"730529";1
24;"395729";43
25;"395423";21
26;"695420";74
27;"665326";54
28;"450929";1
29;"515911";30
30;"576009";74
31;"620209";68
32;"800728";52
33;"486204";73
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use `substring` along with `ifelse` as:

```
# Get the 3rd and 4th character from "birth_number". If it is > 12
# that row is for Female, otherwise Male

df$Gender <- ifelse(as.numeric(substring(df$birth_number,3,4)) > 12, "Female", "Male")

# Now correct the "birth_number". Subtract 50 form middle 2 digits.
# Updated based on feedback from @RuiBarradas to use df$Gender == "Female" 
# to subtract 50 from month number

df$birth_number <- ifelse(df$Gender == "Female", 
                          as.character(as.numeric(df$birth_number)-5000), df$birth_number)

df

#    client_id birth_number district_id Gender
# 1          1       701213          18 Female
# 2          2       450204           1   Male
# 3          3       401009           1 Female
# 4          4       561201           5   Male
# 5          5       600703           5 Female
# 6          6       190922          12   Male
# so on
#
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
'"client_id";"birth_number";"district_id"
1;"706213";18
2;"450204";1
3;"406009";1
4;"561201";5
5;"605703";5
6;"190922";12
7;"290125";15
8;"385221";51
9;"351016";60
10;"430501";57
11;"505822";57
12;"810220";40
13;"745529";54
14;"425622";76
15;"185828";21
16;"190225";21
17;"341013";76
18;"315405";76
19;"421228";47
20;"790104";46
21;"526029";12
22;"696011";1
23;"730529";1
24;"395729";43
25;"395423";21
26;"695420";74
27;"665326";54
28;"450929";1
29;"515911";30
30;"576009";74
31;"620209";68
32;"800728";52
33;"486204";73',
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ";")
```

Comment: Since you already have the gender, in the second condition you can simply do `dat$birth_number <- ifelse(dat$Gender == "Female", etc)`. There's no need for another `as.numeric/substring`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas That's good suggestion. I'll update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same commands as @MKR, I just prefer the `tidyverse` approach.

require(tidyverse)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Gender = ifelse(substr(birth_number, 3, 4) > 12, 
                         "Female", "Male"), 
         birth_number = ifelse(Gender == "Female", 
                               birth_number - 5000, 
                               birth_number)) 


   client_id birth_number district_id Gender
1          1       701213          18 Female
2          2       450204           1   Male
3          3       401009           1 Female
4          4       561201           5   Male
5          5       600703           5 Female
6          6       190922          12   Male
7          7       290125          15   Male
8          8       380221          51 Female
9          9       351016          60   Male
10        10       430501          57   Male
11        11       500822          57 Female
12        12       810220          40   Male
13        13       740529          54 Female
14        14       420622          76 Female
15        15       180828          21 Female
16        16       190225          21   Male
17        17       341013          76   Male
18        18       310405          76 Female
19        19       421228          47   Male
20        20       790104          46   Male
21        21       521029          12 Female
22        22       691011           1 Female
23        23       730529           1   Male
24        24       390729          43 Female
25        25       390423          21 Female
26        26       690420          74 Female
27        27       660326          54 Female
28        28       450929           1   Male
29        29       510911          30 Female
30        30       571009          74 Female
31        31       620209          68   Male
32        32       800728          52   Male
33        33       481204          73 Female
```